# Error while installing magento using xampp

Tags: php, magento, xampp

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xQ2A.png

How can i fix this error,this occured while i was trying to install magento using xampp
Please help me figure it out

Comment: install the things it TELLS you are missing?

Comment: how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all stop the xampp/wamp and then kindly remove the starting semicolon ( ; ) from your xampp/php/php.ini the following code.

;extension=php_intl.dll

;extension=php_xsl.dll

And then restart your xampp.